# computing the difference of a column based on an indicator variable

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I would like to compute the difference between values of column col1 below, based on whether the indicator column is 'grp1' or 'grp2'. I could this manually by creating a subset but that becomes unwieldy. I haven't been able to get something simple to work with group_by:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c('grp1', 'grp2', 'grp1', 'grp2', 'grp1', 'grp2'))
colnames(df) <-  c('col1', 'ind1')
```

My goal is this:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1,2,1,3,4,1,5,6,1), c('grp1', 'grp2','diff', 'grp1', 'grp2','diff', 'grp1', 'grp2','diff'))
colnames(df) <-  colnames('col1', 'ind1')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little kludgey but seems to work.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  mutate(grp = (row_number()+1) %/% 2) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = ind1, values_from = col1) |>
  mutate(diff = grp2 - grp1) |>
  pivot_longer(-grp, names_to = "ind1", values_to = "col1") |>
  select(col1, ind1)
```

Result

```
   col1 ind1 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 grp1 
2     2 grp2 
3     1 diff 
4     3 grp1 
5     4 grp2 
6     1 diff 
7     5 grp1 
8     6 grp2 
9     1 diff
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R we could do this.

```
> split(df, cumsum(c(-1, diff(as.integer(gsub('\\D', '', df$ind1)))) < 0)) |> 
+   lapply(\(x) rbind(x, with(x, data.frame(col1=diff(col1), ind1='dif')))) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind')
    col1 ind1
1.1    1 grp1
1.2    2 grp2
1.3    1  dif
2.3    3 grp1
2.4    4 grp2
2.1    1  dif
3.5    5 grp1
3.6    6 grp2
3.1    1  dif
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that relies on `diff()` and `seq()`

```
bind_rows(
  reframe(df, col1=diff(col1)[seq(1,n(),2)], ind1="diff", o=seq(2.1,n()+1,2)),
  mutate(df, o=row_number())
) %>% arrange(o) %>% select(-o)
```

Output:

```
  col1 ind1
1    1 grp1
2    2 grp2
3    1 diff
4    3 grp1
5    4 grp2
6    1 diff
7    5 grp1
8    6 grp2
9    1 diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something else to try with tidyverse. First group by every 2 rows. Then modify each group by adding a row for "diff" using `add_row` which would contain the difference in `col1` between "grp2" and "grp1".

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(grp = (row_number() + 1) %/% 2) |>
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x, 
                         ind1 = "diff",
                         col1 = .x$col1[.x$ind1 == "grp2"] - .x$col1[.x$ind1 == "grp1"])) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-grp)
```

**Output**

```
   col1 ind1 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 grp1 
2     2 grp2 
3     1 diff 
4     3 grp1 
5     4 grp2 
6     1 diff 
7     5 grp1 
8     6 grp2 
9     1 diff
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood correctly but here is my solution - reformatting to wide format where there are 2 columns (one for each group) you can find the difference of, and then putting it back in long format. [Wide and long format explained here if needed](https://towardsdatascience.com/long-and-wide-formats-in-data-explained-e48d7c9a06cb). Let me know if that isn't quite what you wanted - maybe another example using numbers that don't always have a difference of 1 would help me understand :)

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), c('grp1', 'grp2', 'grp1', 'grp2', 'grp1', 'grp2'))
colnames(df) <-  c('col1', 'ind1')

# create id column put data in long
df$id <- rep(c(1,2,3), each = 2)

# put in long
df_wide <- pivot_wider(df, id_cols=id, names_from=ind1, values_from=col1)

# add column calculating the difference 
df_wide <- df_wide |> mutate(diff = abs(df_wide$grp1-df_wide$grp2))
# put back in long
df <- df_wide |> pivot_longer(cols= c("grp1", "grp2", "diff"), names_to = "ind1", values_to = "col1")
# remove id column
df <- df |> select(!id) |> as.data.frame()
# reorder based on ideal output
df <- df[,c(2,1)]
```